# C Programming: Why is this loop infinite?

Tags: c

```
int main(void) {

int loopControl;


for (loopControl = 0; loopControl <= 6, loopControl+=2;) {

    if(loopControl > 100) {
        break;
    }

    printf("The Loop Control is %d\n", loopControl);
    }
    return 0;   
}
```

Why is this code infinite? I feel like I am missing something basic. I put in the break to read the output.The output is having it loop all the way to 100 and then break due to my if statement.

Comment: Read and fix the compiler warnings; it is very likely your compiler will point out a problem with the for loop.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
for (loopControl = 0; loopControl <= 6, loopControl+=2;)
```

so you are using the comma here it is just a typo,
coma evaluates both then returns the second, so loopControl+=2 is basically always true, you mean:

```
for (loopControl = 0; loopControl <= 6; loopControl+=2)
```

Comment: Sweet lord, I spent way too much time on this for it to be that simple. Thanks a ton!

Comment: Take the advise to **enable compiler warnings** serious. The compiler will tell you exactly where to look for problems, e.g. `loop.c:7:39: warning: left-hand operand of comma expression has no effect [-Wunused-value] for (loopControl = 0; loopControl <= 6, loopControl+=2;)`

Comment: Which compiler gives that warning? On Visual Studio, it gave no warning. Or at least, I am not sure how to enable more warnings than default.

Comment: Also, curious about the logic exactly why it goes infinite. Why does += 6 always equal true? Why does it only evaluate the second or not give an error?

Comment: The coma operator in C is special, it evaluates the left then the right then the r value (c++ term) is the right hand side... something plus something is true unless integer overflow.

Comment: @DudeBro: in Visual Studio, right click the project in Solution Explorer, then click Properties, and in the shown window select C/C++ --> General, and set Warning Level to `"EnableAllWarnings (/Wall)"`.

Answer (score 1):

The increment operator statement is missing in for loop which helps restricting the loop.

In your case third statement is missing in for loop so it is making loop continuous.